# Which developer roles or titles are needed to build a software DAW?

Tags: audio, roles, audio-processing

So far, I've used many different **Audio Production** software on Mac and Windows platforms. Often times, I ponder on the idea of creating my own DAW, but I realize that would be an extremely difficult challenge for a single person to undertake (especially if only knowledgeable in one particular area / language of programming).

There's a flood of ideas / features that comes to my mind just by the thought of some of the other DAWs I've used. From implementing **MIDI** in/out, **Audio Routing**, **Mix Buses**, **VST** support, **User Interface** for a **Piano Roll** and **Song view**, etc...

So my question is...

Which roles would be required in a team of developers to create a complete **Digital Audio Workstation** (DAW) Software?

Comment: -2? The hell is wrong with this community, are people paid by the downvote or something?

Answer (score 2):

I think the right answer is several good developers (you don't need so many, perhaps 3) a good product manager, an ui designer/graphist a lot of testers. *And a good coffee machine.*

The real problem is what kind of DAW do you want, portable on mac and windows, which OSs, which formats (vst 2, 3, AU, RTAS, AAX, rack extension, DX), do you want only MIDI and adio tracks, which external MIDI devices you want to support, do you support OSC, other protocols?

What will be the features of you mixer, integrated effects? What support of audio API on windows (wasapi, asio ...) do you want some cloud feature ? community or online store integration?

What kind of breakthrough would you have compared to cubase, live, PT, DP, Logic, garage band, bitwig, studio one, sonar, fl studio ...? Do you want modular patches or just tracks? Will you have advanced integrated controls or midi modifiers?

All that is the problem...

This is a very complex question!

Comment: Thanks for the enumeration of things to consider. I didn't realize it was that complicated (down to the specific version of each plugin formats!)! I would of thought by now there would be some sort of universal wrappers that can be inserted into any DAW to handle that.